# Want to implement fast csv on nodejs in aws lambda, and giving error: Exit status 129 Runtime.ExitError

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm a newbie in the AWS lambda profile, and I'm trying to publish a data into csv and store it in AWS.

I tried into my local and it's working perfectly, but having an issue when directing the lambda.

Seems like I'm unable to close the  connection for my db.

My snippet of code is :

```
// open the MySQL connection
exports.handler =  (event, context, callback) => {
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false; 
  pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
  // query data from MySQL
  connection.query("select voucher_code as VOUCHER_CODE, STATUS, DATE_FORMAT(order_date, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i') as order_date,WEB_ORDER_ID from RealParsmodel.VOUCHER_REPORT where  DATE(order_date)  = '2020-07-04';", function(error, data, fields) {
  connection.release();

  if (error) callback(error);
  else jsonData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
        console.log("jsonData", jsonData); 

    fastcsv
      .write(jsonData, { headers: true })
      .on("finish", function() {
        console.log("Write to adityakumar successfully!");
      })
      .pipe(ws);
      
  });
});
};
```

Error:

```
{
  "errorType": "Runtime.ExitError",
  Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 129"
}
```

I have a code which works perfectly in local,

```
// open the MySQL connection
pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
  // Use the connection
    connection.query("select voucher_code as VOUCHER_CODE, STATUS, DATE_FORMAT(order_date, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i') as order_date,WEB_ORDER_ID from RealParsmodel.VOUCHER_REPORT where  DATE(order_date)  = '2020-07-04';", function(error, data, fields) {
    // And done with the connection.
    if (error) throw error;

    const jsonData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
    console.log("jsonData", jsonData);

    fastcsv
      .write(jsonData, { headers: true })
      .on("finish", function() {
        console.log("Write to adityakumar successfully!");
      })
      .pipe(ws);

        
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like you're using mysql package, replace it with mysql-serverless package and you should be good

```
npm i serverless-mysql
```